# How to find HTML <style> tag using Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, automation, robotframework

I'm trying to retrieve a value defined in the `<style>` tag in the HTML but keep getting an error that the element can't be found

```
//div[contains(@class,'StageModuleText')]//style
```

Getting this error from RobotFramework

```
Element '//div[contains(@class,'StageModuleText')]//style' not visible after 30 seconds
```

This is the HTML

```
<style>
.item_5b8bfb83-375e-4605-8388-01340ea4bc61_7642733d-4309-4e81-8f64-5a6a55f4994a_d21bf969-efd0-46eb-9545-4cbbd550139e a {
                  color: #bc206e
                } 
</style>
```

I'm trying to get the value of color, but I can't even find the  element. But when the console is open, I can easily find it in the elements tab using the xpath

EDIT:
Here's a wider code sample:

```
<div class="editor-outer    StageModuleText_wrapper__3kHNI item_60036ccd-a7a8-41f3-b858-d0db08f31cfa_06fab0b6-0ab8-4000-a162-7d1dc8bf97c2_b5ce6362-949f-4b81-bf9c-9a0ebc46bc63">
    <style>
        .item_60036ccd-a7a8-41f3-b858-d0db08f31cfa_06fab0b6-0ab8-4000-a162-7d1dc8bf97c2_b5ce6362-949f-4b81-bf9c-9a0ebc46bc63 a { 
            color: #44a1a9 
        }
        .editor_item_60036ccd-a7a8-41f3-b858-d0db08f31cfa_06fab0b6-0ab8-4000-a162-7d1dc8bf97c2_b5ce6362-949f-4b81-bf9c-9a0ebc46bc63 * { 
                  line-height: 1.2 !important;
            }
    </style>
    <div class="editor-wrapper editorwrapper_text editor_item_60036ccd-a7a8-41f3-b858-d0db08f31cfa_06fab0b6-0ab8-4000-a162-7d1dc8bf97c2_b5ce6362-949f-4b81-bf9c-9a0ebc46bc63 StageModuleText_editorWrapper__19Z6l">
        <div id="mce_66c9e9a4_8d68-41e5-b662-d7be6a68391c" tabindex="-1" class="mce-content-body" contenteditable="true" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="txtTinyMce-wrapper" style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 28px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 28px;">
                <p style="font-size: 14px;" data-mce-style="font-size: 14px;">I'm a new Text block ready for your content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *`not visible after 30 seconds`* doesn't mean "*element can't be found*" it means *it's not visible*. Note that `style` node won't be visible in any case

Comment: Can you share relevant HTML or page URL is possible ?

Comment: Why not just use By.tagName("style")

Comment: @Kundan : cause there may be multiple style tags in HTML, and OP certainly does not want the first style tag.

Comment: @cruisepandey I meant to store the div element in a variable and then use findElement(By.tagName()) on that variable. Sorry I was not clear in my first comment. Alternately, can't you just get the text of the div tag and extract the colour value from it?

Comment: This needs wider code sample. But I have thought that it is against good coding practices to have <style> sections this way. Your XPath locator suggests,, that this particular <style> element is inside <div class="StageModuleText someotherclass"></div>

Comment: Hi guys, I have posted a wider code sample. 
@Kundan, I'll try looking if there's an equivalent way to do this through robot framework

Comment: @JaSON, so there's no way to get the details of the style node?

Comment: You can get it. But the problem is probably in your programming code not in XPath

Comment: I don't think so, since I just ran a basic find element on robotframework and it can't find it. Maybe robotframework isn't built to search for <style> tags? I'm in the correct iframe and used a valid xpath, not sure what else is there to change

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With below code I was able to extract the color value

```
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*=editor-outer]"));
    
    String html = ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    String[] arr = html.split("\n");

    for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].contains("color"))
        {
            String color = arr[i].split(":")[1].trim();
            System.out.println(color);
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Implemented something similar in python/RobotFramework. Here's the code for anyone looking

font_color = "css:div[class*=editor-outer]"
element_style = self.selib.get_element_attribute(font_color, "innerHTML")
hex_value = re.search("color: (#.{6})", element_style).group(1).split(',')[0]